# why is Chef File search_file_replace not working

Tags: ruby, regex, chef-infra

I am trying to get this code to replace one attribute and value but it erases the whole line.

```
ruby_block "update connection pool" do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new(servlet_xml_path)
    fe.search_file_replace("maxPoolSize=\"[0-9]+\"", "maxPoolSize=\"20\"")
    fe.write_file
  end  
end
```

The function works if I have a simpler regex like:

```
fe.search_file_replace("maxPoolSize=", "maxPoolSize2=")
```

Comment: Don't know ruby but is `search_file_replace` a regex function. If so, there is nothing in it that should replace the whole line.

Comment: what are you trying to match against?

Comment: @TejayCardon, I am trying to match against maxPoolSize="<any number>" and replace it with maxPoolSize="<my new number>"

Comment: I think you are looking for literal strings (wrapped in quotes) rather than a regex (wrapped in slashes). Try this: `fe.search_file_replace(/maxPoolSize="[0-9]+"/, 'maxPoolSize="20"')`!

Comment: ShellFish is right, and should put in an answer to that point so he/she can get credit for it.  You need to use an actual regex expression

Comment: @TejayCardon, how do I do that? ShellFish gave me the answer I needed.

Comment: You can't do it.  He/She needs to create an answer that you can then accept.  But until that answer is created, you can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

ShellFish provided the answer I was looking for.
fe.search_file_replace(/maxPoolSize="[0-9]+"/, 'maxPoolSize="20"')! –